# Is throwing OutOfMemoryException from application code good design

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I remeber i read somewhere that throwing any of the `System.SystemException` derived exceptions from user code is a bad practice, as user code should only throw application exceptions.

We have an native library that uses the GPU. It may return an error code that indicates that we`re out of GPU memory. We want to translate this error code to a .Net exception.

This are the possible exceptions i can think of:

1. `System.OutOfMemoryException`
2. `System.InvalidOperationException` with appropiate text
3. Custom exception (based on InvalidOperationException)

Which one is the best and why?

Comment: 3 Very good answers in very short time :) I chose @Georg ones as he had the least points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising an `OutOfMemoryException` is the worst choice. The reason for this is that this exception is almost impossible to recover from in the general case and for a client, it is extremely hard to determine whether the system ran out of memory or you just abused this exception type, especially because the client will not expect this behavior.

Raising an `InvalidOperationException` is a better thing, because the client will be able to handle this (by offloading the computation to somewhere else or performing the required stuff in the CPU, potentially using a different library). However, if the exception is an `InvalidOperationException`, this exception type is most likely used also by other libraries or used by the BCL. Thus, the client has to react to this exception by parsing the error message, which is not reliable.

Therefore, the best solution would be a custom exception type, because this will enable clients to just catch this exception type and recover from this situation or tell the user what the problem is. Whether or not you feel that this is a special case of an invalid operation is up to you. Personally, I would not let the exception inherit from `InvalidOperationException` but from `Exception` directly.

Answer (score 4):

Throwing `System.OutOfMemoryException` is not an ideal choice. Programmers who use your library may potentially react to `System.OutOfMemoryException` by purging some of their non-essential objects from memory, and trying again. However, in your case it is GPU memory, not system memory, so their attempt wouldn't have a chance to work.

If users have an option to unload things from GPU memory, directly or indirectly, custom exception approach (number three) provides the cleanest choice. If they have absolutely no control over it, i.e. the exception is basically a "you're dead" message, then `System.InvalidOperationException` is a good choice as well.

Answer (score 2):

The exception thrown should be informative, so let's look for candidates:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx

> An OutOfMemoryException exception has two major causes:
>
> - You are attempting to expand a StringBuilder object beyond the length defined by its StringBuilder.MaxCapacity property.
> - The common language runtime cannot allocate enough contiguous memory to successfully perform an operation. This exception can be
>     thrown by any property assignment or method call that requires a
>     memory allocation. For more information on the cause of the
>     OutOfMemoryException exception, see "Out of Memory" Does Not Refer to
>     Physical Memory.

Having read this I think `System.OutOfMemoryException` is a very wrong candidate: it *misleads* since the problem in your case is with **GPU** not with **RAM**.

The second candiadate is

```
System.InvalidOperationException
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

Another *miss*; the state is OK, it's GPU that doesn't have enough memory.

So I suggest implementing you own *custom exception* which, however, doesn't base on `System.InvalidOperationException` but on `Exception` via abstract `GpuException`:

```
   Exception
     GpuException               // Abstract (wrong GPU, lack of support etc.)
       GpuOutOfMemoryException  // Not enough memory on board
```